# Newbie Problem Understanding Clojure Lazy Sequences

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I've just started learning Clojure and I'm puzzled by how lazy sequences work. In particular, I don't understand why these 2 expressions produce different results in the repl:

```
;; infinite range works OK
(user=> (take 3 (map #(/(- % 5)) (range)))
(-1/5 -1/4 -1/3)

;; finite range causes error
user=> (take 3 (map #(/(- % 5)) (range 1000)))
Error printing return value (ArithmeticException) at clojure.lang.Numbers/divide (Numbers.java:188).
Divide by zero
```

I take the sequence of integers `(0 1 2 3 ...)` and apply a function that subtracts 5 and then takes the reciprocal. Obviously this causes a division-by-zero error if it's applied to 5. But since I'm only taking the first 3 values from a lazy sequence I wasn't expecting to see an exception.

The results are what I expected when I use all the integers, but I get an error if I use the first 1000 integers.

Why are the results different?

Comment: Clojure will sometimes chunk operations on lazy sequences, as a optimization. Why Clojure is chunking one expression but not the other? I do not know. The important thing is that while using lazy sequences the code needs to be such that realizing more elements than asked for still results in correct behavior.

Comment: Thanks Shannon, that certainly explains the behaviour I'm seeing, but I'm disappointed to discover that Clojure does this. It seems to violate referential transparency - the 2 expressions in my post should produce the same result IMO. It also means the docs are not being completely honest - the 'range' doc says it returns a lazy sequence, but actually the sequence is lazyish rather than lazy.

Comment: I agree it's confusing, but I don't think you can say it violates referential transparency. What expression could you swap for its value to produce a different result? The "problem" is that the values produced by `(range)` and `(range 999)` differ in more ways than expected, but you can still replace either of them with their value and get the same result.

Comment: @amalloy My problem is: how should I think about sequences with exceptions?

If I think of sequences as fully lazy then both my expressions should work. 

On the other hand, if I think of sequences as fully evaluated (not literally) then both expressions should throw exceptions.

Neither interpretation  works. I guess the problem for me is more basic than referential transparency. My expressions don't even have deterministic values (since they may or may not throw exceptions depending on chunking).

I guess the takeaway for me is to follow ShannonSeverance's advice and be careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure 1.1 introduced "chunked" sequences,

> This can provide greater efficiency ... Consumption of chunked-seqs as
> normal seqs should be completely transparent. However, note that some
> sequence processing will occur up to 32 elements at a time. This could
> matter to you if you are relying on full laziness to preclude the
> generation of any non-consumed results. [Section 2.3 of ["Changes to Clojure in Version 1.1"](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/1.1.x/changes.txt)]

In your example `(range)` seems to be producing a seq that realizes one element at a time and `(range 999)` is producing a chunked seq. `map` will consume a chunked seq a chunk at a time, producing a chunked seq. So when take asks for the first element of the chunked seq, function passed to map is called 32 times on the values 0 through 31.

I believe it is wisest to code in such a way the code will still work  for any seq producing function/arity if that function produces a chunked seq with an arbitrarily large chunk.

I do not know if one writes a seq producing function that is not chunked if one can rely in current and future versions of library functions like map and filter to not convert the seq into a chunked seq.

**But, why the difference?** What are the implementation details such that `(range)` and `(range 999)` are different in the sort of seq produced?

1. Range is implemented in [clojure.core](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3019).
2. `(range)` is defined as `(iterate inc' 0)`.
3. Ultimately iterate's functionality is provided by the Iterate class in [Iterate.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Iterate.java).
4. `(range end)` is defined, when end is a long, as `(clojure.lang.LongRange/create end)`
5. The LongRange class lives in [LongRange.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LongRange.java).

Looking at the two java files it can be seen that the LongRange class implements `IChunkedSeq` and the Iterator class does not. (Exercise left for the reader.)

**Speculation**

1. The implementation of clojure.lang.Iterator does not chunk because iterator can be given a function of arbitrary complexity and the efficiency from chunking can easily be overwhelmed by computing more values than needed.
2. The implementation of `(range)` relies on iterator instead of a custom optimized Java class that does chunking because the `(range)` case is not believed to be common enough to warrant optimization.

Comment: I think I have a mental model now. An expression involving clojure seqs will produce the same result as a similar expression using fully-lazy seqs subject to the condition that realising unrequested elements has no observable side-effects (like throwing exceptions). So as long as I avoid side-effects (and exceptions) I can reason about seqs as if they were fully-lazy. My example expressions did not meet this condition, so divergent behaviour shouldn't have surprised me. Thanks to you and @amalloy for your help.